# Apache AuthBasicProvider : how to specify password format?

Tags: apache, basic-authentication, mod-auth

I am using the 'mod_auth_basic' and 'mod_authn_dbd' apache modules to authenticate users.

How can I specify the password format I want mod_auth_basic to use? I don't find this in the documentation.

(Available formats can be found there: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/misc/password_encryptions.html)

Here is a sample of my configuration:

```
<Directory "/usr/www/fake>
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Fake"
  AuthBasicProvider dbd

  AuthDBDUserPWQuery "SELECT password FROM authn WHERE user = %s"
</Directory>
```

Comment: There should be no need to specify it, it can be determined from hash prefix.

Comment: A prefix is mandatory? Why would it be?

Comment: It is described so in the first paragraph of the above Docs url

Comment: And again below, in "Database password fields for mod_dbd"